# IronPython: SQLite error (26): file is encrypted or is not a database

Tags: python, sqlite, ironpython

I am testing the Iron Python to connect to a base SQLITE3 by running Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and I've got this error:

"SQLite error (26): file is encrypted or is not a database"

My Workstation Win7_x64, is System.Data.SQLite_x86 (netFx40-setup-sqlite-bundle-1.0.79.0-x86-2010)

Please I need help.

I've created a new base with the "SQLite Data Browser".

My script is:

```
def RunQuery(self, query):
    conn = SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + self._path + ";Version="+self._version+";Password="+self._password)
    conn.Open()
    set = DataSet()
    adapter = SQLiteDataAdapter(query, conn)

    try:
        adapter.Fill(set)
    finally:
        conn.Close()

    return set
```

Sorry the previous message! It was sent from a mobile phone.

Comment: Is your file encrypted or not a database? Give some more detail and maybe someone can help you. Did you create your sqlite database yourself? Try creating one and reading it again in the same script, and tell us what happens (with code).

Comment: I've created a new base with the "SQLite Data Browser". My script is:
conn = SQLiteConnection ("Data Source =" + + self._path ", Version =" + + self._version ", Password =" + self._password)
         conn.Open ()
         DataSet set = ()
         adapter = SQLiteDataAdapter (query, conn)
        
         try:
             adapter.Fill (set)
         finally:
             conn.Close ()
            
         return in Set

Comment: please edit your question and format your code appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to resolve the problem. The error was in the method call "SQLiteConnection" with password:

of:

```
SQLiteConnection ("Data Source =" + + self._path ", Version =" + + self._version ", Password =" + self._password)
```

to:

```
SQLiteConnection ("Data Source =" + + self._path ", Version =" self._version + + ";")
```

In SQLite3, does not need password.